# List contain different datatypes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, types, contain

I want to store values of different data types in a list and retrieve them as it is, such as:

```
1. 5
2. True
3. PersonName
4. 0.325
```

is it possible?

Comment: Which language are you working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming C# is the language)

You can use a `List<object>` to store the values. And while retrieving the values you have to cast those properly.